# There is MFC project. I need to make it independent of MFC. I need a clone of CString

Tags: c++, mfc, cstring

There is the project using MFC CString. I want to make it independent of MFC. Is there independent CString class with same methods?

Comment: There is no string implementation that offers all functionality of `CString`. I doubt you are using the functionality in its entirety, so it would help if you provided a list of operations you need.

Comment: Is there implementation that offers general functionality of CString? I need +, Format, Find, Mid, Trim.

Comment: What is *"general functionality"* to you? Querying a character sequence's length? `std::string`/`std::wstring` (and probably any other string implementation) have that. Conversion constructors/operators to convert between UNICODE and ASCII strings? Few string implementations will give you that. Please provide a concrete list of functionality you need.

Comment: Have a look at this old Codeproject article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1146/CString-clone-Using-Standard-C

Answer (score 3):

CString is independent of MFC.

```
#include <atlstr.h>
```

Comment: @Ufx: If you're using Qt, why didn't you say so in your question? More importantly, why aren't you moving to `QString`?